# Dead Code encountered with x fatal warnings on

Tags: scala

I have a piece of code:

```
case class ColumnChange private(field: String, old: Option[JsValue], `new`: Option[JsValue])

@typeclass
trait CreateColumnChanges[-New] {
  def fieldChanges(newValue: New): Vector[ColumnChange]
}

trait LowLevelFieldChangesImplicits {
  import com.github.ghik.silencer.silent

  @silent
  implicit object NothingColumnChanges extends CreateColumnChanges[Nothing] {
    override def columnChanges(newValue: Nothing): Vector[ColumnChange] = Vector.empty
  }
}
```

I have enabled `"-Xfatal-warnings"` in my `build.sbt`.

When I am compiling my project its throwing this error:

```
 dead code following this construct
[error]   implicit object NothingCreateFieldChanges extends CreateFieldChanges[Nothing] {
```

I tried changing type to `CreateColumnChanges[Any]`, but somehow many tests are failing, which over-complicates my problem, maybe because `-New` is in contravariant position. I tried putting this `scalacOptions "-Ywarn-dead-code"` in build file too, but its not having any effect and again I am getting the same exception. I am compiling with scala `2.12.10`.Also `@silent` annotation is not having effect on it. How can I change my code to avoid this error.

Comment: I don't see `implicit object NothingCreateFieldChanges extends CreateFieldChanges[Nothing]` in the code snippet and `implicit object NoColumnChanges extends CreateColumnChanges[Nothing]` compiles with no warnings for me in 2.12.10.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this worked,

I changed type from `Nothing` to `Unit`